# The proof of inequality about diameter.

Tags: inequality

> Let $A(\neq \phi)$ be a set , $\epsilon >0$ and $G=\{ x \in \mathbb{R^n} | d(x, A) < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} \delta (A) \}$. $\delta (A)$ means diameter of $A$, i.e $\delta (A)=$sup {$ d(x,y) | x,y\in A\} .$

I want to prove $\delta (G)\leqq (1+\epsilon) \delta (A)$.

I could understand by drawing a picture but I couldn't prove it with a mathematical formula.

I would like you to give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Take $x, y\in G$, and let $a, a' \in A$ such that $d(x,a) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}\delta(A)$ and $d(y,a) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}\delta(A)$. The triangle inequality gives $d(x,y) \leqq d(x,a) + d(a,a') + d(a',y)$. Show that this implies $d(x,y) \leqq (1 + \epsilon)\delta(A)$. Since $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary, $\delta(G) \leqq (1 + \epsilon)\delta(A)$.